# Can't give a margin to an element in the right place

Tags: html, css, margin

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
 HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers 
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}


////////////* CSS reset end *////////////////



body{
    background: #fff;
  
}

h1,h2,h3,h4 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

p,a {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

header {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px 0;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 1;
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
}

header:after{
    content: "";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 96%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 2%; 
}

div#logo {
    background: url(img/logo.png) no-repeat;
    width: 79px;
    height: 28px;
    float: left;
}

header nav {
    float:right;
    
}

header nav li a {
    color:#606060;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:12px;
    
}

header nav h2 {
    height: 0;
    text-indent: -10000px;
}

header nav li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 22px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

#main-banner {
    background: url(img/2.jpg) no-repeat center center ;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 80vh;
    text-align: center;  

}

.banner-overlay {
    text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 margin: 0;
 transform: translatey(-50%);
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 72px;
    
}

.banner-overlay .after-welcome {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 0 20%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    
    
}

.btn {
/*    background: #bf8040;*/
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f0b7a1 0%,#752201 100%,#bf6e4e 100%,#752201 100%); 
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 25px 20px;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700; 
}


section {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 125px 0;
}

#gallery {
    background: #dfdfdf;
}

h2 {
   color:#282828;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 45px;
   
}

h3 {
    color:#777;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:75px;
}


.projects {
    background: #fff;
}

section:after{
    content: "";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}

.gallery-image {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
    padding-left:1.5%;
    padding-right:1.5%;
    text-align: center; 

}

#gallery img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;       
}

.gallery-image a {
  display: block;
  background: white;
}

.img-text {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.img-text p{
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#777;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.margin-top {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <main>
        <section id="gallery">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h2>Our Gallery</h2>
                <h3>Lorem bizzle dolizzle sizzle amet</h3>
                <div class="projects">
                    <div class="gallery-image">
                        <a href=""> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg" alt="gallery-image"></a>
                        <div class="img-text">
                            <h4>A project</h4>
                            <p>Some text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="projects">
                    <div class="gallery-image">
                        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg" alt="gallery-image"></a>
                        <div class="img-text">
                            <h4>A project</h4>
                            <p>Some text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="projects">
                    <div class="gallery-image">
                        <a href=""> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg" alt="gallery-image"></a>
                        <div class="img-text">
                            <h4>A project</h4>
                            <p>Some text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
              
              <p class="margin-top">Lorem bizzle dolizzle sizzle amet</p>
              
          </div>
       </section>
```

I'm trying to add a `<p>` and give it a margin top, so that the content in it is further away from the gallery content but it gives that marginon top of the images.

How should I solve this ? Maybe it's a clearfix problem if I'm not mistaken, but the clearfix didn't help.

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Kestvir/pen/BReraN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it's a clearfix issue because of the 3 floated elements above it. Add a wrapper to those `.projects` elements and clear the floats.

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
 HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers 
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}


////////////* CSS reset end *////////////////



body{
    background: #fff;
  
}

h1,h2,h3,h4 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

p,a {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

header {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px 0;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 1;
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
}

header:after{
    content: "";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 96%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 2%; 
}

div#logo {
    background: url(img/logo.png) no-repeat;
    width: 79px;
    height: 28px;
    float: left;
}

header nav {
    float:right;
    
}

header nav li a {
    color:#606060;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:12px;
    
}

header nav h2 {
    height: 0;
    text-indent: -10000px;
}

header nav li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 22px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

#main-banner {
    background: url(img/2.jpg) no-repeat center center ;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 80vh;
    text-align: center;  

}

.banner-overlay {
    text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 margin: 0;
 transform: translatey(-50%);
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 72px;
    
}

.banner-overlay .after-welcome {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 0 20%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    
    
}

.btn {
/*    background: #bf8040;*/
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f0b7a1 0%,#752201 100%,#bf6e4e 100%,#752201 100%); 
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 25px 20px;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700; 
}


section {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 125px 0;
}

#gallery {
    background: #dfdfdf;
}

h2 {
   color:#282828;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 45px;
   
}

h3 {
    color:#777;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:75px;
}


.projects {
    background: #fff;
}

section:after{
    content: "";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}

.gallery-image {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
    padding-left:1.5%;
    padding-right:1.5%;
    text-align: center; 

}

#gallery img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;       
}

.gallery-image a {
  display: block;
  background: white;
}

.img-text {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.img-text p{
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#777;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.margin-top {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.projects-container:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section id="gallery">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h2>Our Gallery</h2>
      <h3>Lorem bizzle dolizzle sizzle amet</h3>
      <div class="projects-container">
        <div class="projects">
          <div class="gallery-image">
            <a href=""> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg" alt="gallery-image"></a>
            <div class="img-text">
              <h4>A project</h4>
              <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="projects">
          <div class="gallery-image">
            <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg" alt="gallery-image"></a>
            <div class="img-text">
              <h4>A project</h4>
              <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="projects">
          <div class="gallery-image">
            <a href=""> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg" alt="gallery-image"></a>
            <div class="img-text">
              <h4>A project</h4>
              <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <p class="margin-top">Lorem bizzle dolizzle sizzle amet</p>

    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `display: inline-block;` to the paragraph.

Let me explain myself:

```
p{
  display:block;
}
```

Now `p` margins will work so the "Lorem bizzle dolizzle sizzle amet" sentence after projects is going to go down as it has margin-top.

Comment: You should put your answer in the context of the question, by itself it's not clear how it answers the question.

Comment: I don't see why copying the full snippet without more explanations is better than extracting the right part.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `clear:both` div just above `<p>` tag

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

CHECK BELOW SNIPPET

```css
      
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
 HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers 
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}


////////////* CSS reset end *////////////////



body{
    background: #fff;
  
}

h1,h2,h3,h4 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

p,a {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

header {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px 0;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 1;
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
}

header:after{
    content: "";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 96%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 2%; 
}

div#logo {
    background: url(img/logo.png) no-repeat;
    width: 79px;
    height: 28px;
    float: left;
}

header nav {
    float:right;
    
}

header nav li a {
    color:#606060;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:12px;
    
}

header nav h2 {
    height: 0;
    text-indent: -10000px;
}

header nav li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 22px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

#main-banner {
    background: url(img/2.jpg) no-repeat center center ;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 80vh;
    text-align: center;  

}

.banner-overlay {
    text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 margin: 0;
 transform: translatey(-50%);
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 72px;
    
}

.banner-overlay .after-welcome {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 0 20%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    
    
}

.btn {
/*    background: #bf8040;*/
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f0b7a1 0%,#752201 100%,#bf6e4e 100%,#752201 100%); 
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 25px 20px;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700; 
}


section {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 125px 0;
}

#gallery {
    background: #dfdfdf;
}

h2 {
   color:#282828;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 45px;
   
}

h3 {
    color:#777;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:75px;
}


.projects {
    background: #fff;
}

section:after{
    content: "";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}

.gallery-image {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
    padding-left:1.5%;
    padding-right:1.5%;
    text-align: center; 

}

#gallery img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;       
}

.gallery-image a {
  display: block;
  background: white;
}

.img-text {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.img-text p{
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#777;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.margin-top {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <main>
        <section id="gallery">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h2>Our Gallery</h2>
                <h3>Lorem bizzle dolizzle sizzle amet</h3>
                <div class="projects">
                    <div class="gallery-image">
                        <a href=""> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg" alt="gallery-image"></a>
                        <div class="img-text">
                            <h4>A project</h4>
                            <p>Some text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="projects">
                    <div class="gallery-image">
                        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg" alt="gallery-image"></a>
                        <div class="img-text">
                            <h4>A project</h4>
                            <p>Some text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="projects">
                    <div class="gallery-image">
                        <a href=""> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg" alt="gallery-image"></a>
                        <div class="img-text">
                            <h4>A project</h4>
                            <p>Some text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
              <div style="clear: both;"></div>
              <p class="margin-top">Lorem bizzle dolizzle sizzle amet</p>
              
          </div>
       </section>
</main>
```